# How To Use Effort in Conjunction with Reverse Poco Generator

Tags: c#, testing, entity-framework-6, effort

So I am Visual Studio 2017, EF6 and I am using this T4 template https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator to generate my context class

Being a big fan of testing I already have 100% coverage with unit tests, but now I want to do Integration tests where I can call multiple parts of my system and pass through the changes - but of course I want to do this without touching a real disk DB.

So after searching for a bit I found Effort https://entityframework-effort.net/ and to me this looks like exactly what I want to use. Where I can create a database thats in memory, fill it with whatever fixtures I want and than call multiple methods from various parts of my system. However, the thing I am trying to find out is how to make it work in my situation I have tried DBConnectionFactory, EntityConnectionFactory, ObjectConnectionFactory and every time I get the Error Message:-

"EffortException: Database has not been initialized".

this is the code block I am using in my setup:-

```
   var newsCtx = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePersistent("2");
   _newsEntities = new NewsEntities(newsCtx);
   _newsEntities.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
   _newsEntities.Channels.Add(new Channel
   {
            Id = 1,
            Title = "Convenience Store - ",
            Link = "https://www.conveniencestore.co.uk/XmlServers/navsectionRSS.aspx?navsectioncode=123",
            Description = "https://www.conveniencestore.co.uk",
            Image = "https://www.conveniencestore.co.uk/magazine/dest/graphics/logo/logo.png",
            PublishedAt = null,
            UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2),
            Enabled = true,
            Type = "Rss_2_0",
            Author = null,
            Category = null,
            Copyright = null,
            Generator = null
   });
   _newsEntities.SaveChanges();
```

When I get to the saveChanges I get the exception which suggests that I add the .CreateIfNotExists() which I have already done, however, I still get the error. I can see samples and examples on various links where it works... however I dont want to abandon my t4 template as it gives me exactly what I want.

I am a little lost and I am wondering has anybody used a reverse poco generator that creates the context and used this in conjunction with Effort. I would love to use both and If somebody can give me a pointer so that I can get decent integration tests working with in memory DB I would be as happy as a sandboy

Regards Julian

this is the generated method in the Poco from the t4 template

```
    public NewsEntities(System.Data.Common.DbConnection existingConnection)
        : base(existingConnection, true)
    {
        this.Database.Connection.Open();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try using the CreateTransient method instead of CreatePersistent? We used that in mulitple projects and it works just fine

Comment: yes I have tried CreateTransient.

Comment: So I guess it gave you the same result? We use it like this
        [Fact]
        public void Can_Create_Context()
        {
            DbConnection con = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();
            using (var db = new MyDbContext(con))
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

and it works great. The difference is that we don't have a Call to CreateIfNotExists

Comment: I think my issue is the Reverse Poco Generator. - Are you using that in conjunction with Effort. - i *think* that is where my issue lies

Comment: No we've used both, but never in conjuction. How does the constructor of your context look like? Could you add that to your question? Is it calling the base constructor and passing down the connection?

Comment: We had to add this constructor to your context in order to get effort working:
        public MyDbContext(DbConnection connection)
            : base(connection, true)
        {
        }

Comment: I have modified the Reverse Poco generator to include exactly this and I have tried with true and false.
        public NewsEntities(System.Data.Common.DbConnection existingConnection)
            : base(existingConnection, false)
        {
            this.Database.Connection.Open();
        }

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after reviewing https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/11/using-an-in-memory-database-as-a-test-double-with-entity-framework/ this link, I got to wondering about how my reverse poco generator was behaving in the methods I had the following inside the method

this.Database.Connection.Open();

this was causing the problem.... removing this line from the .ttinclude poco generator enabled Effort to run. Why this was there I have no idea, and removing it doesnt seem to have an effect.

Therefore, I am happy as a sand boy again and I can continue with my integration tests using an in memory database. If you come across this problem see if somebody has modified your t4 template to do something different.